# AWS S3 specify etag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use the sha256 sum of my object as the etag. I am using the following code to try to specify the etag:

```
aws s3 cp foo-lambda.zip s3://foo-bucket/lambda-code/foo-lambda/foo-lambda.zip --metadata ETag=FkyOB6C4wZQz5w9ClCMKxnK8A0iqCk4RWSO0Epbbc4I= --profile foo-profile
```

This operation succeeds with no error messages or warnings. However, the etag in the AWS S3 console does not match this value; it is instead the MD5 sum of the zip. I have tried deleting the object and uploading it again with the same results.

EDIT: here is more information from the command line

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket foo-bucket --key lambda-code/foo-lambda/foo-lambda.zip --profile foo-profile
```

response

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ContentType": "application/zip",
    "LastModified": "Mon, 01 May 2017 18:17:11 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 584,
    "ETag": "\"729439461018d55c885e56b858e54676\"",
    "Metadata": {
        "etag": "FkyOB6C4wZQz5w9ClCMKxnK8A0iqCk4RWSO0Epbbc4I="
    }
}
```

So note that the `ETag` value is wrong, but the `Metadata.etag` value is the one I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon uses the etag for various tasks in the system. You'll have to continue using the metadata like you proposed in your question.

> ETag
>   The entity tag is a hash of the object. The ETag reflects changes only to the contents of an object, not its metadata. The ETag may or may not be an MD5 digest of the object data. Whether or not it is depends on how the object was created and how it is encrypted as described below:
>
> - Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-S3 or plaintext, have ETags that are an **MD5 digest** of their object data.
> - Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-C or SSE-KMS, have ETags that are **not an MD5 digest** of their object data.
> - If an object is created by either the Multipart Upload or Part Copy operation, **the ETag is not an MD5 digest**, regardless of the method of encryption.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html